# Passing specific character/number/ text inside the combobox to a variable in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following items in my combobox:
<1, 5 to 9, 10 to 15, 16 to 25, 30 to 40, 40 to 45.
I want to pass the values from index 1 to my varaible int age for value '5' and int age2 for value '9' excluding the word 'to' 
How can i get values and pass it to my variables without including the string "to"

Comment: try splitting on a space and then get the values from the resulting list/array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work ::

```
if (this.cmbAge.Text != "")
        {
            int age = 0, age1 = 0;

            string[] strAge = this.cmbAge.Text.Split(new string[] { "to" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            age = Convert.ToInt32(strAge[0]);
            if (strAge.Length == 2)
                age1 = Convert.ToInt32(strAge[1]);

            MessageBox.Show("Age = " + age + "\r\nAge1 = " + age1);
        }
```

Output :: [image]

Comment: It worked. But getting error on items "<1" and "50 >". I tried adding "<", ">" in string array strAge.

Comment: You can't store '>' or '<' in int type variable, For conversion of string include '>' or '<' we may use                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                age = Convert.ToInt32(strAge[0].Replace("<","").Replace(">",""));

Comment: I will just omit the  '<' and '>' to get the integer in "<1" and "50>"  i tried the line elseif (strAge.Length ==1) and added the < and > in the string[] strAge, but getting errors.